# prettyPhoto doesn't work on other pages

Tags: jquery, html, prettyphoto

I have problems with prettyPhoto. It works perfectly on my other page called: portfolio.html. 
In the Index.html I also wanted to make some images work with prettyPhoto but it doesn't respond on the code. I have this:

In the top of my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
```

The middle:

```
  <div class="boxA">
                <a href="images/images/barn_owl.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is the description"><img class="bottom" src="images/knop-hover1.jpg" />
                <img class="top" src="images/knop-1.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
            <div class="boxB">
            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="images/images/siamang.jpg"><img class="bottom" src="images/knop-hover-siamang.jpg" />
              <img class="top" src="images/knop-siamang.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
            <div class="boxC">
                <a href="portfolio-cover.html"><img class="bottom" src="images/knop-hover-cover.jpg" />
              <img class="top" src="images/knop-cover.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
```

The bottom:

```
<script>
//prettyPhoto 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a[data-gal]').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).attr('rel', jQuery(this).data('gal'));
    });     
    jQuery("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'slow',theme:'light_square',slideshow:false,overlay_gallery: false,social_tools:false,deeplinking:false});
}); 


</script>
```

If anyone knows prettyPhoto I hope you can help me. Thnx.

Comment: 1) did you remember to include jQuery on index.html? 2) what does the javascript console output when you navigate to index.html?

Comment: Did you include jQuery? And which version of PrettyPhoto and jQuery are you using? - I've just worked with PrettyPhoto today and found out that the latest version of PrettyPhoto doesn't play well with the latest version of jQuery :)

Comment: @EsbenBoye-Jacobsen I did include the jQuery under in my index.html. The version of this one is 3.1.5

Comment: @JosephMarikle I don't understand what you mean (my english is not that good sorry). I have inlcude the jQuery to my index.html. It's at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Ok, then (according to my tests) you should use jQuery version 1.8.3 or below... Otherwise you will get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined ` :)

Comment: You can view those messages by opening the javascript console. in chrome it's menu (top right)->Tools->JavaScript Console.  Whatever is output there would be good to know.

Comment: @JosephMarikle well...it says Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. I am such a beginner with jQuery so I don't know how to show it.

Comment: @Veavictis If that's the case, then it's not loading jQuery before it tries to execute the prettyPhoto.  Is the part where you add jQuery before or after the script you included in your question?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I put the jQuery script after the html tag at the bottom. :o The script link of prettyPhoto in the head.

Comment: Well, for starters, your script tags should not be outside the `<html>` tag.  They should be inside the `<body>` tag or the `<head>` tag.  The order should probably be jQuery, prettyPhoto, your script.  If prettyPhoto is in the head, add jquery before it.  Your other script should be fine if you place it in the body tag

Comment: Haha I thought so..but it still doesn't work. :(